# Web page loading time code snippet works fine only for https sites

Tags: ios, loading, html

The below code snippet written for iOS app ( Finding web page loading time) works fine only for https websites. But when i try to give http sites it shows web page loading error. Which part of the code should i change?

```
self.setTextLabel.text = @"Loading...";
    NSURL *urlValue = [NSURL URLWithString:_textView.text];
    NSURLRequest *request= [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlValue];
    NSDate *start=[NSDate date];
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    /*NSURLSessionDataTask *task =[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error)
    {*/
    NSDate *end=[NSDate date];
        if(response != nil)
        {
            double ellapsedSeconds= [end timeIntervalSinceDate:start];
            self.setTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f ", ellapsedSeconds];

        }
        else
        {
            self.setTextLabel.text = @"Web Page Loading error !";

        }
```

Comment: you  have to add NSAppTransportSecurity key in your info.plist  <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>

Answer (score 1):

First you need to do this :  Open Info.plist, and add the following lines:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

1) If you're using a webview then

//lets say this is where you load the request and you already have your webview set up with a delegate

```
-(void)loadRequest{

      [webView loadRequest:yourRequest];
      startDate=[NSDate date];
   }
```

//this is the delegate call back for UIWebView

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
   NSDate *endDate=[NSDate date];
   double ellapsedSeconds= [endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
}
```

2) Without webview :

```
 NSDate *start=[NSDate date];
    NSURLRequest *r= [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url]; 
    NSData *response=   [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:r returningResponse:nil error:nil];
   NSDate *end=[NSDate date];
 double ellapsedSeconds= [start timeIntervalSinceDate:end];
```

Comment: It is still not working! And arc mechanism doesnt allow explicit auto release

Comment: Thx Corrected for ARC version. can you be more specific what is not working? can provide the log of that?

Comment: I type a url in my textbox suppose https://google.com and it gives me the loading time. But when i type http://saavn.com it gives webpage loading error.